# Bootstrap .... Removing margin of div container

Tags: bootstrap-5

```
<div class="row  row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">
```

.I want to remove the left and right margin of this div container using bootstrap.
For removing it I have used the class mx-0.
Like This

```
<div class="row  row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4  mx-0">
```

But its Not Working .
How to solve this issue ? . Thanks

Comment: You are right, `mx-0` is the correct utility class for zero horizontal margin. So it should work. What is the calculated value for horizontal margin on your element?

Answer (score 0):

There is no margin set for any of those classes.  Your margin is coming from parent class ... e.g. `<body>` sets a margin of 8px.

You need to set the `mx-0` in the parent.  Or override your div with some custom css, e.g.,

```css
margin-left: -8px;
margin-right: -8px;
```

*(This is not exactly what you need, but I don't have your parent code so showing you an arb. example.)*